# longest substring with exclude list of strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am using [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Java) algorithm to find common substring between 2 strings. Please, help me to do this but with using `Array` of common substrings of this strings, which I should ignore in my function.

My Code in Java:

```
public static String longestSubstring(String str1, String str2) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (str1 == null || str1.isEmpty() || str2 == null || str2.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }

        // java initializes them already with 0
        int[][] num = new int[str1.length()][str2.length()];
        int maxlen = 0;
        int lastSubsBegin = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
                if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) {
                    if ((i == 0) || (j == 0)) {
                        num[i][j] = 1;
                    } else {
                        num[i][j] = 1 + num[i - 1][j - 1];
                    }

                    if (num[i][j] > maxlen) {
                        maxlen = num[i][j];
                        // generate substring from str1 => i
                        int thisSubsBegin = i - num[i][j] + 1;
                        if (lastSubsBegin == thisSubsBegin) {
                            //if the current LCS is the same as the last time this block ran
                            sb.append(str1.charAt(i));
                        } else {
                            //this block resets the string builder if a different LCS is found
                            lastSubsBegin = thisSubsBegin;
                            sb = new StringBuilder();
                            sb.append(str1.substring(lastSubsBegin, i + 1));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

So, my function should looks like:

```
public static String longestSubstring(String str1, String str2, String[] ignore)
```

Comment: What problem are you currently facing with your solution? Seems like good code, to me.

Comment: There is no problem with the code. Read the last statement

Comment: As a side note: in many cases your set of ignored strings (stop words) is better off being stored in a Hash Map / Dictionary data structure. This is because a large list of ignored words will cripple your algorithm if you have to iterate over it every time. My suggestion for your algorithm is to construct this HashMap, and then at the depth of your loop when you generate the substring, ping the word to see if it exists in the ignored words Hash and only add it if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have to ignore those substrings that contain at least one string from `ignore`.

```
if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) {
    if ((i == 0) || (j == 0)) {
        num[i][j] = 1;
    } else {
        num[i][j] = 1 + num[i - 1][j - 1];
    }


    // we must update `sb` on every step so that we can compare it with `ignore`
    int thisSubsBegin = i - num[i][j] + 1;
    if (lastSubsBegin == thisSubsBegin) {
        sb.append(str1.charAt(i));
    } else {
        lastSubsBegin = thisSubsBegin;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(str1.substring(lastSubsBegin, i + 1));
    }

    // check whether current substring contains any string from `ignore`,
    // and if it does, find the longest one
    int biggestIndex = -1; 
    for (String s : ignore) {
        int startIndex = sb.lastIndexOf(s);
        if (startIndex > biggestIndex) {
            biggestIndex = startIndex;    
        }
    }    

    //Then sb.substring(biggestIndex + 1) will not contain strings to be ignored 
    sb = sb.substring(biggestIndex + 1);
    num[i][j] -= (biggestIndex + 1);

    if (num[i][j] > maxlen) {
        maxlen = num[i][j];
    }
}
```

If you have to ignore those substrings that are *exactly* the same as any string in `ignore`,
then when the candidate for longest common substring is found, iterate over `ignore` and check whether there is current substring in it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a suffix tree of one of your strings and run through the second to see which substring can be found in the suffix tree.

Info on suffixtrees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffixtree